# Why is PHP mysqli prepared statement working but inserting all NULL values?

Tags: php, mysql, null, mysqli

What would cause this? Code follows:

```
$m = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) die('Connect failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
$PrepSQL  = "INSERT INTO Products (" . implode(',',$this->cols) . ") VALUES (";
$PrepSQL .= '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $m->prepare($PrepSQL);
if(!$stmt) die('Could not prepare: ' . $m->error . "\n$PrepSQL\n");
$ret = $stmt->bind_param('isissssddssssssssssssssssssssssssisssssss',
      $contents[0], ... bunch of these here ... );
if(!$ret) die('bind_param failed: ' . $m->error);
```

Then in a loop I have:

```
$contents = explode('|',$NL); // NL is pipe delimited data
print_r($contents); 
if(!$stmt->execute()) die("Statement failed: " . $m->error);
```

And the script doesn't halt but every value is null in MySQL. Most of the types are strings and I would assume they would at least fill in even if the numeric types are wrong. The `print_r` is printing values correctly.

Comment: Line 4 ends in the wrong quote character.

Comment: That was a typo after the paste when I was trying to format.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->cols` contains the correct column names?

Comment: Basic debugging first. What does `$contents[0]` contain?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the responses. As I mentioned above, code executes with zero warnings and no errors. The print_r produces output. $this->cols contains the correct data (i.e. $content is fine) and $content[0] => 467187964 ... mysql is getting inserts, I have some default columns a auto inc PK and a timestamp and they're being filled just fine, but all other columns are null. Thanks for your responses everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the complete code from preparing the statement to executing it?

I suspect that $contents in the first part is not the same $contents as in the second part. They need to be references to the same array, since you're populating it after binding it by reference.

Comment: I think you're right. My PHP skills are very behind. Doing the assignment again was probably doing something else.